# FolderPicker crashes when not attached to debugger

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, picker, win-universal-app

I'm trying to figure out what could be wrong here. When I run the below code through Visual Studio when connected with the debugger everything works as it should. But when I run the code without any connection to Visual Studio the app instantly crashes.

Is there something I'm missing - I've made the required changes for continuation in my app and everything works as expected. Just not when I'm off Visual Studio.

```
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.ContinuationData["Operation"] = "DownloadFile";
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
folderPicker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured this one out. For some reason it was the

```
continuationManager.MarkAsStale();
```

in the `OnSuspending()` in `App.xaml.cs` removing this fixed all problems.

Note this also stopped the app from showing in the multi task section.